# Android java client suddenly stopping

Tags: java, android, server, client

I creates a Java server on my computer and a client in my Android application. Everything was going fine but suddenly the client has stopped to send data to the server. Often the client sends data for 3 to 5 times, but sometimes it doesn't works anymore.

I use the Intent Service for the client.
I am not adding my Java server, because I don't think there is a problem with a server.

My Intent Service

```
package com.example.finch.ornek_proje;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Objects;


public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = MyIntentService.class.getSimpleName();
    String [] trend_list;
    String file_size;
    int filesize;
    int read2 = 0;
    int totalRead = 0;
    int remaining;
    byte [] bytes;
    private static final int SERVERPORT = 2001;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.45";

    public MyIntentService() {
        super("MyIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        Log.i(TAG,"starting");
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            InputStream input_stream = socket.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(input_stream);
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input_stream));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                true);
            out.println("get_trend_list:0");
            String read = input.readLine();
            String [] infos;
            trend_list = read.split(",");
            for (int b = 0;b < 10; b++){
                out.println("get_vd_info_less:"+ trend_list[b]);
                read = input.readLine();
                infos = read.split(",");
            }
            out.println("shutdown:0");
            dataInputStream.close();
            input_stream.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            bytes = new byte[4096];
            for (int b = 0;b < 10; b++){
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
                InputStream input_stream = socket.getInputStream();
                DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(input_stream);
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input_stream));
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                    true);
                out.println("get_vd_img1:"+ trend_list[b]);
                file_size = input.readLine();
                filesize = Integer.valueOf(file_size);
                remaining = filesize;
                String filepath = getFilesDir().getPath() +"img"+Integer.toString(b)+".png";
                File file = new File(filepath);
                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                while ((read2 = dataInputStream.read(bytes, 0, Math.min(bytes.length, remaining))) > 0){
                    totalRead += read2;
                    remaining -= read2;
                    outputStream.write(bytes,0,read2);
                }
                outputStream.close();
                filesize = 0;
                read2 = 0;
                totalRead = 0;
                remaining = 0;
                bytes = new byte[4096];
                out.println("shutdown:0");
                socket.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            bytes = new byte[4096];
            for (int b = 0;b < 10; b++){
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
                InputStream input_stream = socket.getInputStream();
                DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(input_stream);
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input_stream));
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                    true);
                Log.d("abcv", String.valueOf(b));
                out.println("get_vd_img2:"+ trend_list[b]);
                Log.d("abcv", String.valueOf(b));
                file_size = input.readLine();
                filesize = Integer.valueOf(file_size);
                remaining = filesize;
                String filepath = getFilesDir().getPath() +"img"+Integer.toString(b+10)+".png";
                File file = new File(filepath);
                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                Log.d("abc","abc");
                Log.d("abcv", String.valueOf(filesize));
                while ((read2 = dataInputStream.read(bytes, 0, Math.min(bytes.length, remaining))) > 0){
                    totalRead += read2;
                    remaining -= read2;
                    outputStream.write(bytes,0,read2);
                    Log.d("abcv", String.valueOf(b));
                }
                Log.d("abcv", String.valueOf(b));
                outputStream.close();
                filesize = 0;
                read2 = 0;
                totalRead = 0;
                remaining = 0;
                bytes = new byte[4096];
                out.println("shutdown:0");
                socket.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        Log.i(TAG,"closing");
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: check your log files for any exceptions